# Android apk won't install from the market nor web server

Tags: android

This is my own application developed with the intention of distributing it via the Android market. It's been tested on several handsets, installed each time with from the SDK (so, adb).
However that appears to be the only way I can install it:

- I signed the application and uploaded it to my own server.
- Any previous version is uninstalled from the device:
- Downloading via the browser results in a silent fail. Server logs show that there was only one access (a successful OTA install requires, I believe, two request/responses). There is nothing at all in Logcat.
- I tried instead releasing it to the Android Market. This time Logcat indicates a server-side error:
  DEBUG/vending(530): [42] BaseAction.run(): ApiException: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.PurchaseOrderRequest, Response=INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
  DEBUG/vending(530): [1] LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): -7763566390739351724 / UNINSTALLED
  DEBUG/vending(530): [1] LocalAssetCache.updateOneAsset(): No local info for -7763566390739351724
  INFO/vending(530): [1] BaseAction.displayErrorUi(): Server error in com.android.vending.billing.PurchaseOrderAction: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.PurchaseOrderRequest, Response=INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR

The most likely problem, then, is how I signed the application. However the signed version can be installed via adb on the command line and even from gmail. Furthermore I signed a small, unrelated application with exactly the same results. I've also tried building from another machine and under Windows and Linux. Same results every time, on three different devices, factory reset, over the internet or WIFI. The only constant is me.

I've read literally every thread on stackoverflow regarding the above error in Logcat, all of which appear to be unrelated because I have no difficulty installing other applications from the Android market.

I've exhausted my meagre wits trying to debug this and would be very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Did you check that your certificate is generated right, i.e. that it's valid for at least 25 years etc.?

Comment: With regard to the Web server scenario, make sure your Web server is set up to serve the APK file with the correct MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`).

Comment: Regarding the generation of the certificate, I entered 35 years as the validity period (on several occasions now) and ran jarsigner -verify. I think it's valid but if there's anything I might have overlooked I'd welcome any thoughts.

Comment: As for the mime type, I'm actually fairly sure that the web server is NOT set up correctly - I'm using Google App Engine's blobserver with out of the box functionality. However this reminds me to mention that in fact this scenario was working about six months ago, when I last tried it. Never-the-less I'm going to explicitly set the MIME type and try again and report back to this thread. 
Thanks again for the feedback so far.

Comment: Update - it's not the mime type. I've set that explicitly to application/vnd.android.package-archive and the download still fails (or at any rate the installation doesn't begin).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that android:debuggable="false" in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Do this test while disabling USB Debugging on the test device.

Also make sure to remove any calls that invoke the debugger like android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()

You might have to just create a new certificate.

Comment: Thanks for this. android:debuggable isn't set at all, which I believe means that it defaults to false. I'm not using any debugging code in the application.
I've raised the issue with android market support, so I fear that creating a new certificate would only confuse things, in that it would mean creating a new content item.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. The numerous forum entries suggest that there are many possible causes of this problem but in my case it was down to the fact that I was trying to buy my own application, which is apparently against policy. I was testing my first paying app and frankly I thought the responsible thing to do was spend my own money to ensure a good experience for others. The solution was to purchase the application with a different google checkout account.
This resolution was provided by a very responsive android market support, for which I'm grateful. 
It would also appear that I was experiencing two different errors. The one preventing me from downloading my app from my own server persists, but is clearly unrelated.
I hope this entry is of help to others. Thanks to those who commented.